# Derivation of the relationship between snellen rows and diopters

Tags: optometry, lenses

The results of converting between rows of a snellen chart and diopters is indicated in the tables at these two links: [How to Convert Diopters to 20/20 Vision](https://goldeneyeoptometry.com/2018/03/12/20-20-vision/) and [Conversion Table for Distance Vision](https://www.happyeyesight.com/get-20-20-vision/)

But:  **What is the derivation of the relationship between rows of a snellen chart and diopters?**

Comment: I've searched a lot(I think so :) ) but I haven't found any derivation at least in the medical texts in only those in my reach ;) I believe this question still is good for Physics SE.

Comment: Here's an _incorrect_ derivation -- results in the correct sign but too small a value:  Interpret "20/40 correction" to mean that when a lens of power d_lens is placed in front of the eye, objects at 12 m form an image at the same location (retina) as objects at 6 m would for the naked eye.  Assume the ciliary muscles do not change the power of the naked eye, d_eye, when viewing objects at 6 m or 12 m.  So we have the two equations:

    1/6 + 1/v = d_eye;  and 
    1/12 + 1/v = d_lens + d_eye;
    And solving them yields:  d_lens = -1/12 = -0.08